# Problem starting Electron app - [603:0827/215406.435140:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(264)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, electron

I am trying to set up a electron project. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app) and the previous ones.

But when I get to "Running your App" and type `npm start`, I get the following message:

```
 myApp@1.0.0 start ***PATH***
 electron .

[603:0827/215406.435140:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(264)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
***PATH***/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myApp@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myApp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tobias/.npm/_logs/2020-08-27T11_54_06_541Z-debug.log
```

npm version: `6.14.6`
node.js version: `12.18.3`
I'm using the WSL terminal in Visual Studio code.

I have tried installing the electron-quick-start package with the same outcome.

Comment: Don't run your app as root...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it helps but in your package.json try changing the start script into

```
"start": "electron --no-sandbox ."
```